# MongoDB $push is not actually pushing anything onto the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I commented the line of code with `// This Command Does not work` where I suspect that it is breaking. In the debug log of mongoose, the output looks like this: But nothing is added to the medicineIds array in the Monday object for the DaysOfWeek schema.

The following is the debug output for DayOfWeek.findOneAndUpdate() where I push back onto the array, and am not seeing the result in my mongo database.

```
Mongoose: dayofweeks.insertOne({ medicineIds: [], _id: 'Monday', __v: 0 }, { session: null }) // <- response to $push
```

```
Mongoose: medicines.insertOne({ times: [ 1, 2 ], dayNames: [ 'Monday' ], _id: ObjectId("5e73d816d54b1202e15bb96b"), nam
e: 'Provolone', count: 23, __v: 0 }, { session: null })
Mongoose: dayofweeks.findOne({ _id: 'Monday' }, { projection: {} })
```

**Mutation**

```js
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addDayOfWeek: {
            type: DayOfWeekType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
                let dayOfWeek = new DayOfWeek({
                    _id: args.name,
                    medicineIds: new Array()
                });

                return dayOfWeek.save(); 
            }
        },
        addNewMedicine: {
            type: MedicineType,
            args: {
                name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
                count: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
                times: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(GraphQLInt))},
                dayNames: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLList(GraphQLString))}
            },

            resolve (parent, args) {
                let medicine = new Medicine({
                    name: args.name,
                    count: args.count,
                    times: args.times,
                    dayNames: args.dayNames
                }); 
                args.dayNames.forEach((dayId) => {
                    DayOfWeek.findOneAndUpdate( // This Command Does Not Work: 
                        // medicine._id, dayId are correct at this point of the 
                        //code
                        { _id: dayId }, 
                        { $push: { medicineIds: medicine._id }},
                        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
                    );

                });
                return medicine.save(); 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**DayOfWeek Schema**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

const dayOfWeekSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    medicineIds: [String] // I am trying to push onto this array
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DayOfWeek', dayOfWeekSchema);
```

**Medicine Schema**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

const medicineSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    count: Number,
    name: String,
    times: [Number],
    dayNames: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Medicine', medicineSchema);
```

Comment: At this line: `{ $push: { medicineIds: medicine._id }}`, if the `medicine` object has not yet been saved, does it have an `_id` field?

Comment: ```{ times: [ 1, 2 ],
  dayNames: [ 'Monday' ],
  _id: 5e73d190b925d602667fa85c,
  name: 'Provolone',
  count: 23 }
Monday
5e73d190b925d602667fa85c``` Is output for console.log(medicine), so yes. I will check if this is the actual ID, of the saved medication. Even then, the list of the dayOfWeek should recieve an ID even though it may not be the correct one right?

Comment: I don't see where the console.log was called.  Generally, if you don't explicitly set a value for `_id` that field won't exist until after you save the object.

Comment: Try adding the `findOneAndUpdate` after the `medicine.save()` i.e something like this `medicine.save().then(() => { args.dayNames.forEach( ...update code... ) }`.

Comment: It was exiting the function and then not fulfilling the promise, because findOneAndUpdate returns a promise, so I had to await an array of all the promises.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 await Promise.all(args.dayNames.map(dayName => {
                    return DayOfWeek.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: dayName }, { $push: { medicineIds: medicine._id }});
                })).catch((err) => console.error(err)); 

                return await medicine.save();
```

I just did that and it works. hmm.